# Batch file to open 3 programs and a folder - I'm almost there

Tags: excel, batch-file

Batch file Requirement;
I need to open 1) WindSailor 2) Addons Linker 3) folder (drive) "O" and 4) Excel-01. MSFS.xlsm.
The issue is - when Excel opens, it is **not** set to autosave via OneDrive. I have to set it to autosave manually after it opens.

I have 1 .bat file that opens 1, 2 and 3 perfectly.

```
@echo off
start "" "C:\Users\Dad\Desktop\WindSailor"
start "" "C:\Users\Dad\Desktop\Addons Linker"
start "" "O:\"
```

And I have a second .bat file that opens Excel perfectly - all set for autosave via OneDrive.

```
@echo off
set params=%*
start excel "E:\OneDrive\03. Excel\02. Flight Sim\01. MSFS\01. MSFS.xlsm" /e/%params%
```

But when I combine the two, Excel opens but **not** set to autosave...

```
@echo off
start "" "C:\Users\Dad\Desktop\WindSailor"
start "" "C:\Users\Dad\Desktop\Addons Linker"
start "" "O:\"
set params=%*
start excel "E:\OneDrive\03. Excel\02. Flight Sim\01. MSFS\01. MSFS.xlsm" /e/%params%
```

I have tried countless variations - what am I missing ?

Comment: Try yo add a `pause` command before launching Excel. Maybe opening drive `O:\\ ` blocks something in OneDrive, forbidding Excel to enable it automatically. If it works, then you could use the `timeout` command instead to wait a given amount of time automatically and without needing to press ENTER.